# Training neural network classifier with one class after another

Tags: neural-network, classification, training

Is it possible to train a neural network classifier with only one class, and after that with only another class? 
For example, first train it only on recognizing dogs, and after finishing that training, only train it on recognizing cats, so in the end the net can classify between dogs and cats.

Or do the classes always need to be mixed for training?
Please tell me any scientific papers explaining why classes have to be mixed or explaining why they do not need to be mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably work  but less **Efficiently**(or lower Accuracy) if you train the Network one after the another (like trained for Dog's first , followed by Cats etc..) because

- It will `Change The Weights of The Hidden Layers` which in turn will destroy the same Recognition Capability of The Network ...
- Also Dogs and Cats `differ in their natural looks a lot`, So the Net Will Have a tough Time Doing So Simultaneously..

**But**

What You Can Do is either of the followings -

- Train Two Neural Nets Simultaneously or Train them one after the another but saving the Weights of the Layers somewhere for all your Training.. And Then Predict What the Net thinks the input image to be..
- Better Will Be To Train a CNN to do the same Task with Ease and will Achieve Better Accuracy.
- If you only have dogs and cats, then it will be sufficient to only train on one of them i.e if it isn't a dog, then its surely a cat..

Why we prefer mixing of similar Image Groups?

It's more of Human Nature to do a task which can en-compass similar things at once, rather than doing the particular tasks repeatedly..

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know any papers dealing with that?